# Avoid run time in looping

Tags: r, loops, apply

Test is my database which I want to pull values i.e. emp id vector and I have a another file named as User from which I want to pull values.

Test Database

Name  Emp ID
A
B
C
D
A

User file

Name  Emp ID
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
A       1

I have two conditions in my loop. I find matching values then only I pick it and if there are duplicates I pick only one. I used this loop. It takes 3 hours. I have dataframe and for 300000+ rows in my user file from where I want values.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Test))
{`enter code here`
if(Test[i,"Name"] %in% User_Name)
{
item_id_found<-Test[i,"Name"]Test[i,"Emp_ID"]<-as.numeric(User[which(User$Name==item_id_found),"Emp_ID"])[1]}}
```

I need to know a shorter way like apply function. I want the result in data frame and not matrix or lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply merge the two datasets if I understand your problem correctly. But, before we merge, we 1) drop the `Emp_ID` variable from `test`, and 2) dedup `user`. This approach assumes that `Emp_ID` will be the same for all rows with the same `Name`.

```
x <- merge(test[, 1], user[!duplicated(user$Name), ], by = "Name")
x
  Name Emp_Id
1    A      1
2    B      2
3    C      3
4    D      4
```

### Update

Based on the information in the comments, we need to account for a) values in `test$Name` not being present in `user$Name`, and b) dropping variable from `user` that we don't want. This can still be done with `merge`, we just need to add some new options.

```
test <- data.frame(Name = c(LETTERS[1:6], "A", "E"), Emp_ID = NA, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
user <- data.frame(Name = c(LETTERS[1:4], "A"), Emp_ID = c(1:4, 1))
x <- merge(subset(test, select = -c(Emp_ID)), user[!duplicated(user$Name), c("Name", "Emp_ID")], by = "Name", all.x = TRUE)
x
#   Name Emp_ID
# 1    A      1
# 2    A      1
# 3    B      2
# 4    C      3
# 5    D      4
# 6    E     NA
# 7    E     NA
# 8    F     NA
```

We use `subset` to get rid of the `Emp_ID` variable in `test` since we're going to be merging it on. We use `!duplicated` to dedup `user` and then specifically state to only keep `Name` and `Emp_ID`. Lastly, we pass `all.x = TRUE` to the `merge` function to ensure that any values in `test` not found in `user` won't be dropped.

To address the last issue, which is merging if `test` and `user` don't share the same variable of `Name`, we just tweak the `merge` function a little more.

```
names(user) <- c("Emp_Name", "Emp_ID")
x <- merge(subset(test, select = -c(Emp_ID)), user[!duplicated(user$Emp_Name), c("Emp_Name", "Emp_ID")], by.x = "Name", by.y = "Emp_Name", all.x = TRUE)
x
#   Name Emp_ID
# 1    A      1
# 2    A      1
# 3    B      2
# 4    C      3
# 5    D      4
# 6    E     NA
# 7    E     NA
# 8    F     NA
```

Comment: I dont think this is what i was looking for. Lets say if test has another element E and status does not have that element then it is not returning NA instead in test it is returning D. Also if lets say user has a coloumn which i do not want to merge with test. How do I remove in this function itself.

Comment: What is status? Is that a variable in `test`? Is that the actual name of what you're calling `user`? And if you only want `Emp_ID` from `user` then simply state that in the merge statement. `x <- merge(test[, 1], user[! duplicated(user$name), "Emp_ID"], by = "Name")`.

Comment: Lets say if test has another element E and user does not have that element then it is not returning NA instead in test it is returning D. Also if lets say user has a coloumn which i do not want to merge with test. How do I remove in this function itself. In your above function if lets say  user and test has different labels for the same vector. Like in user it is Name and in Test it is name so will this function which you posted will work or I will have to merge it by using by.x=name and by.y=Name

Comment: I'll edit my answer to account for the new conditions.